# Showing related products in product view page

Tags: magento-1.7, product, product-linking

I'm working on a website where I'm using Magento 1.7. I want to display the related product of the current product on product view page. I tried [many](http://importantmagento.blogspot.in/2012/08/magento-get-all-related-products-of.html) links like [these](http://www.voodish.co.uk/articles/related-products-on-product-page-in-magento/), but none of them worked for me. Please help me on this. I'm newbie to magento.

Comment: which page layout is used for product view page? generally related product are display in right bar by default on product view page.

Comment: I don't want that to be display on right bar or left. I want to be displayed on product detail page. that is view.phtml of product.

Comment: Yes i am asking you which page layout is used for product detail page? if you are using 1column layout then you will consider philwinkle answer

Comment: I used two columns with left bar.

Comment: Ok so your related products are not display, look for my answer for display related product

Answer (score 10):

This is built in to most themes and all of the base themes. So I'm guessing what you want is to **relocate** the related products to another area.

This is possible in a few different ways:

**Via layouts**

Using layout XML you can provide the following block declaration to any `<reference>` -

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" before="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
```

This should call and render the block and associated template file.

**Roll your own**

Why not? You're a capable developer! In this case, you can do something very similar to what you posted in the links above. This particular example is fairly trivial but shows you what may be possible:

### Edit

My what a difference a year makes. Don't load models in loops. **Bad Phillip, BAD**.

```
$related_prods = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array('in'=>$_product->getRelatedProductIds()));
foreach($related_prods as $related){
    echo $related->getName() . " " . $related->getSku(); 
}
```

This can be placed anywhere on the product page or `view.phtml` but **best practice** dictates that you should place this in a Block method and reference that inside the template. Bottom line, you either need to have $_product available or use `Mage::registry('current_product')`.

Comment: Why not load product collection instead? Something like ```Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('product_id', array('in' => $relatedIds));``` Better than loading Model inside a loop IMHO.

Comment: Or even easier: ```$product->getRelatedProductCollection()```

Comment: Absolutely, this is just an example.  I also didn't include the standard warming against using getmodel in a loop.

Comment: There's a missing semicolon after `$related_prods = $_product->getRelatedProductIds()`.

Comment: @shmuli I have updated this (ancient) answer for a best practice approach and to fix the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check this block in `catalog.xml`

```
 <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" before="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
```

just put like this if you want to display in your content area

```
 <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" after="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
        </reference>
```

save file and clear your cache.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the reference to the block related_products from view.phtml

```
<?php //echo $this->getChildHtml('related_products') ?>
```

Then add this to anywhere you want in view.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('catalog.product.related'); ?>
```